# Number of integral solutions for an equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations

How do we approach this kind of problem of finding number of positive integral solutions to
$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{n!}$$

Here $n$ is given.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions, eg $x=y=2\cdot n!$

Comment: Isn't $n$ fixed ?

Comment: YES n is fixed @charMD

Comment: There are a huge number of solutions for $n$ of any size. Mathematica gives 1148 solutions with $x\ge y$ for $n=10$.

Comment: @THERE is no constraint on x and y as x>y or y>x

Answer (score 2):

Let $(x,y)$ be a solution. We isolate $x$ : $\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{n!} - \frac{1}{y}$. We need $y>n!$. Also $x = \frac{n! y}{y - n!}$.

Hence $y - n! \mid n! y$. The number of pairs solutions $(x,y)$ is the number of integers $y>n!$ such that $y - n! \mid n! y$. Let us find the number of such integers.

We write $y = n! + \alpha$. Then it becomes $\alpha \mid n!(n!+\alpha)$, so $\alpha \mid (n!)^2$. Denoting $d( (n!)^2)$ the number of divisors of $(n!)^2$, there are exactly $d( (n!)^2 )$ possible values for $\alpha$, therefore for $y$, therefore for the pairs.

**Finally there are $d( (n!)^2 )$ solutions** (number of divisors of $(n!)^2$)

$ $

*(For $n=10$, you find $2295$ non-ordered pairs)*

Answer (score 0):

$$n!(x+y)=xy$$
$$xy-n!(x+y)=0$$
$$xy-n!(x+y)+(n!)^2=(n!)^2$$
$$(x-n!)(y-n!)=(n!)^2$$

Now, one can express $(n!)^2$ as a product of two factors and generate solutions for $x$ and $y$.